# History of Dynamic Logic

Tags: logic, math-history, predicate-logic, modal-logic

Does anyone know any good source where I could find some history of PDL? I'm writing a paper on PDL and I'd like to add an introduction containing important historical facts(people who contributed most to it, why was it needed, what it is used for), just like my professor did in his course.

Sadly, the only bits of history I've found (Wikipedia and Stanford's Encyclopedia of Philosophy) don't offer to much information.

Thanks to anyone who can point out a website/book/article or who'll be willing to write on this subject as an answer!

Comment: Maybe useful : J. van Eijck & M. Stokhof, “The Gamut of Dynamic Logics”, in D. Gabbay and J. Woods (eds.), [The Handbook of History of Logic, Volume 7 Logic and the Modalities in the Twentieth Century](https://books.google.it/books?id=gpwZYXsomEsC&pg=PA499) (2006), pp.499–600.